# How to test physical mouse on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, mouse

Android 8 adds support for pointer capture. 
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html#pointer-capture

Is there any way how can I test it in android emulator? By default mouse emulates touch events, even I call requestPointerCapture with successful result.

Comment: The same would be useful for testing [Tooltips](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/tooltips.html)-- I see no easy way to test hovering besides using an actual Android 8 device.  I kinda remember a way to attach a physical device and forward events to the emulator but not sure if it's still supported.

Comment: I did not found way how to test these features in emulator. I am waiting for someone with android 8 device around me :(